# Gauge Taiko: given selector list/count encountered itens

Tags: javascript, getgauge

I'm using Gauge/Taiko to automate some scenarios and I'm struggling with some basic stuff.

Given a selector that match N elements: is there a way to list/count those elements?
Today even I provide a selector that matchs N elements, it returns only the 1st match.

example:

```
$('.input')
```

returns only the first element with the class *input*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To just find the number of matching elements `(await $('#id').get()).length` can be used,  to access element by index there is an open issue for the same https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues/288

Update:

`get()` is now deprecated in taiko. And taiko supports accessing elements by index. Do use `(await $('#id').elements()).length`

Comment: Upvote this answer and adding that for anyone that is trying to assert on count, you need to use direct node `assert`: `assert.equal((await text(`MY LABEL`).elements()).length, 2)`.  See: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_equal_actual_expected_message